# Tensor products and vector valued functions

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, tensor-products

Given a non-empty set $S$ and a Banach space $X$. Let $B(S,X)$ be the space of all bounded maps from $S$ to $X$. Can we identify $B(S,X)$ with $\ell^\infty(S) \otimes X$, where $\otimes$ is some kind of tensor product of Banach spaces?

Answer (score 9):

I don't think so.

A tensor product of Banach spaces generally means a completion of the algebraic tensor product under some norm.  In this case the algebraic tensor product $\ell^\infty(S) \otimes_a X$ embeds naturally into $B(S,X)$, whose norm is given.  So the question becomes, whether $\ell^\infty(S) \otimes_a X$ is dense in $B(S,X)$, and the answer in general is no.

Let $S = \mathbb{N}$ and let $X$ be an infinite dimensional separable Banach space.  Choose a sequence $x_n$ which is dense in the unit sphere of $X$. Define $f : S \to X$ by $f(n) = x_n$, so $f \in B(S,X)$.  But for any $g \in \ell^\infty(S) \otimes_a X$, the range of $g$ is contained in a finite dimensional subspace $E_g$ of $X$.  By Hahn-Banach we can find $x$ in the unit sphere with $d(x, E_g) > 1/2$, and by density there is $x_n$ with $||x_n - x|| < 1/4$.   Thus $\sup_n ||g(n) - f(n)|| > 1/4$ so $f$ is not in the closure of $\ell^\infty(S) \otimes X$.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you.

Comment: Thus, there is no better description of $B(S,X)$ than $C(\beta S, X)$, where $S$ carries the discrete topology...

Comment: @balzac: This might be a very naive question, but why does $C(\beta S, X) = B(S,X)$?  The universal property of $\beta S$ guarantees that continuous functions on $S$ valued in a compact space extend to $\beta S$, but bounded subsets of $X$ need not be precompact.

Comment: You're right: I am wrong. Btw, correct me if I am wrong: if $S$ is uncountable then there exist $f\in B(S,\mathbb{R})$ which is not a uniform limit of functions taking finitely many values?

Comment: @balzac: No.  Any $f \in B(S, \mathbb{R})$ is a uniform limit of functions taking finitely many values.  For instance, say $0 \le f \le 1$; then if $f(x) \in [k/n, (k+1)/n)$, set $f_n(x) = k/n$, and we have $||f - f_n||_\infty \le 1/n$.  More generally, this works for any function taking values in a totally bounded metric space.

Comment: @balzac:  It may remind you of the theorem from measure theory that any measurable function $f$ is a limit of simple functions; if you inspect the proof, you'll see that when $f$ is bounded, the convergence is uniform.  Indeed, if we equip $S$ with the discrete $\sigma$-algebra $2^S$, it is the same theorem.

Comment: Ok, the last question: Let $X$ be a normed space and $\overline{X}$ its completion. Is it true that $\overline{B(S,E)}=B(S, \overline{E})$?

Comment: @balzac: Why not try proving it yourself?