# How to describe the space $L_{\infty}(\mu,X)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, tensor-products

Given a Banach space $X$ and a measure space $(\mathfrak{A}, \mu)$ One can form the Banach space $L_\infty(\mu, X)$ of all measurable, essentially bounded functions from $\mathfrak{A}$ to $X$. Is it obvious that one can identify $L_\infty(\mu, X)$ with the projective tensor product $L_\infty(\mu)\hat{\otimes}X$? If I am mistaken (that is, this is not true), can we find another tensor product to make such identification?

EDIT: Since the answer is 'no', I would appreciate any other 'reasonable' descriptions of the Banach space $L_\infty(\mu, X)$, if there are any.

Comment: See Nate's answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/46743) which says it doesn't work for $\mathbb{N}$ with counting measure and *any* tensor product that arises as a completion of the algebraic tensor product.

Comment: Thank you. I should have searched for it first.

Comment: Just to make sure: Are you now asking about an identification of the projective tensor product $L_\infty(\mu) \mathbin{\hat{\otimes}} X$ or about $L_\infty(\mu,X)$?

Comment: I ask about $L_\infty(\mu, X)$. Thanks for keeping an eye on my edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what counts as "reasonable", but here's one idea.  You can form the projective tensor product $L^1(\mu) \widehat\otimes X^*$, and this *is* isometrically isomorphic to $L^1(\mu,X^*)$.  Then $L^\infty(\mu,X)$ always forms a subspace of $L^1(\mu,X^*)^*$.  But we can identify the latter as
$$ L^1(\mu,X^*)^* = ( L^1(\mu) \widehat\otimes X^* )^* = B(L^1(\mu), X^{**}) $$
that is, bounded linear maps $L^1(\mu) \rightarrow X^{**}$.  So you can always view $L^\infty(\mu,X)$ as a collection of bounded linear maps $L^1(\mu) \rightarrow X^{**}$.  In fact, it's easy to see that you always get a map $L^1(\mu) \rightarrow X$.  I don't know if that's any help...

**Aside:** It's a subtle question as to when $L^\infty(\mu,Y^*) = L^1(\mu,Y)^*$.  This holds if and only if $Y^*$ has the Radon-Nikodym Property-- for example, if $Y$ is reflexive, or $Y^*$ is separable.  This can be found in e.g. the Appendix of Defant+Floret's book, or the book of Diestel and Uhl.

Comment: I take it that you're talking about finite measures, right? By the way: Defant-Floret contains a good and very useful collection of facts, but very often they refer to Diestel-Uhl for details.

Comment: Ah, yep, finite measures!  Thanks...  I guess if your space is "decomposable", so $L^1(\mu) = \ell^1(L^1(\mu_i))$ for some collection of finite measures $\mu_i$ (with associated measurability criteria) then you could decompose everything, and work with block matrices-- i.e. messy, but not impossible.